# How to fix line numbers in Go test output?

Tags: testing, go

Let's consider this simple testing code.

*(Note: `assertSomething` is super simple here, but normally I'd write a more specialised helper for the task at hand that would look at multiple things and could report more than one type of error.)*

```
package hello

import "testing"

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    assertSomething(t, 2+2 == 4) // line 6
    assertSomething(t, 2+3 == 6) // line 7
}

func assertSomething(t *testing.T, expected bool) {
    if !expected {
        t.Error("Something's not right") // line 12
    }
}
```

When I run `go test`, I get the following:

```
--- FAIL: TestFoo (0.00s)
    hello.go:12: Something's not right
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    kos/hello   0.008s
```

I have two questions:

1) The error points to line 12 - why? How does `t.Error` find out which line it was called from?

2) In the helper, I'd like to specify that `t.Error` should look stack level higher to determine the line number to print, so that I would get a message like this:

```
--- FAIL: TestFoo (0.00s)
    hello.go:7: Something's not right
```

Python allows me to do this, for instance, in [`warnings.warn("message", stacklevel=2)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn) - how would I implement the equivalent here?

Comment: As far as 1 is concerned, it likely uses [runtime.Caller](http://godoc.org/runtime#Caller) for this purpose. Supply a different number for `skip` to go up some levels. I am not sure you can tell `test.XXX` to do this without changing the test package code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Things have [changed](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/4899-testing-helper.md) since go 1.9.

`Helper()` method has been added to `testing.T` and `testing.B`. It's intended to be invoked from testing helpers such as `assertSomething` to indicate the function is a helper and we're not interested in line numbers coming from it.

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    assertSomething(t, 2+2 == 4) // line 6
    assertSomething(t, 2+3 == 6) // line 7
}

func assertSomething(t *testing.T, expected bool) {
    if !expected {
        t.Helper()
        t.Error("Something's not right") // line 12
    }
}
```

The output contains correct line numbers:

```
=== RUN   TestFoo
--- FAIL: TestFoo (0.00s)
    main.go:7: Something's not right
FAIL
```

You can also [try it](https://play.golang.org/p/gV3JPikcO-S) on Go Playground.

Comment: Very very nice! Thanks for info. Also not such bad design from Go side :P

Answer (score 12):

You *can* do what you're asking, and you can find out how `t.Error` works by [looking at the source code](https://golang.org/src/testing/testing.go?s=17291:17427#L474). The function [`decorate`](https://golang.org/src/testing/testing.go?s=11236:11498#L282) is what you're looking for I think.

But, in the case where you have significant amounts of checking code, and for some reason it's getting duplicated in your test, it's better to extract that as a function that returns an error than passing in a testing.T and making it an "assertion". Indeed, writing assertion functions is explicitly discouraged in the language [FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/faq#testing_framework).

```
package hello

import "testing"

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    if err := checkSomething(2+2 == 4); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("2+2=4 failed: %s", err)
    }
    if err := checkSomething(2+3 == 6); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("2+3=6 failed: %s", err)
    }
}

func checkSomething(v bool) error {
    if !v {
        return errors.New("something's not right")
    }
    return nil
}
```

But here's what I think idiomatic testing code would look like. It's table-driven, and the cases include inputs and expected output, leading to really clear error messages when the tests fail.

```
package hello

import "testing"

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    cases := []struct {
        a, b, want int
    }{
        {2, 2, 4},
        {2, 3, 6},
    }
    for _, c := range cases {
        if got := operation(c.a, c.b); got != c.want {
            t.Errorf("operation(%d, %d) = %d, want %d", c.a, c.b, got, c.want)
        }
    }
}

func operation(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. And for testing stateful async code, is there a more idiomatic approach than "put something in one channel, assert there's something at another channel, repeat"? Any examples I can refer to? I don't think I can write that table-driven.

Comment: Alas, more complex test helpers (not assertions) are useful and need to adjust the call level for exactly the reasons documented in that FAQ entry - if they perform multiple checks, they should be able to add multiple failures. The magic to add the call site is unfortunately buried in an unexported helper (the decorate method), so adding this feature requires a fair chunk of duplication or an alternative testing library. As an example, you may want to repeat the same series of tests on several objects implementing an interface